# JqueryUI datepicker, buttontext as value

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to get the buttontext of datepicker (which defaults to an ellipsis), to set itself as the value of the input.

I have multiple datepickers on the page, and unlike my example below I have an icon instead of a text input. I would like the value itself to show on the tooltip that appears when you hover over the icon.

I have tried - `buttonText: $(this).val()` as an option but it doesn't pick anything up

Example - http://jsbin.com/unolot/3/

**So my question** - How do I get the buttontext of the datepicker input to match the value dynamically?

Comment: you can make use of altfield option in DatePicker api

Comment: you want textbox value as an tooltip on the icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle two cases:

- When the selected date changes: use the `onSelect` event to change the button's title attribute
- On initial rendering: unfortunately, the datepicker does not implement the widget factory (yet) so there is no `create` event, you'll have to update the title attribute *manually* after the widget has initialized.

*Don't forget to set the default date of the picker to the initial value of the field, otherwise the default selected date is "today"*

Something like this:

```
// as you have several instances, loops through them
$(".deadline_picker_on").each(function() {

    var dt = $(this);

    dt.datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonText: '',
        // set the default date to the value of the field
        defaultDate: dt.val(),
        duration: 100,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showOptions: {
            direction: 'right'
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            // on data selection, change the title attribute of the button
            $(this).next().attr('title', dateText);
        }
    })
    // get the button (next element)
    .next()
    // set the title attribute with the formatted initial date from the picker
    .attr('title', $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dt.datepicker('getDate')));
});
​
```